# How to make an array of graphic circles that I can redraw to the screen on intervals?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw circles on the screen but I want to store them in an array for later use in building a centipede type game. I am somewhat new to object in Javascript.

My object is Circles as below.

```
function Circles(x,y,r) {
    var cX = x;
    var cY = y;
    var cR = r;
}
```

I want to create an array of say 50 circles that I can loop through and display to the screen because currently I have a square that moves around the screen that I can control with the left and right keys.

I want to redraw the array to the screen.

**How can I create the array?"

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theCanvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvasContext=theCanvas.getContext("2d");
var radX;
var radY;
var radR;
var context;
var numCircle = 50;
var circleArray = new Circles(50);

function Circles(x,y,r) {
    var cX = x;
    var cY = y;
    var cR = r;
}

function clearCanvas() {
  //context.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}

function drawCircle(x,y,r,context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
}

function getRandomColor() {
    // creating a random number between 0 and 255 -- this will set the color of the random sized circle
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);

    // going from decimal to hex -- converts the int value to a hex for the color
    var hexR = r.toString(16);
    var hexG = g.toString(16);
    var hexB = b.toString(16);

    // making sure single character values are prepended with a "0"
    if (hexR.length == 1) hexR = "0" + hexR;
    if (hexG.length == 1) hexG = "0" + hexG;
    if (hexB.length == 1) hexB = "0" + hexB;

    // creating the hex value by concatenatening the string values
    var hexColor = "#" + hexR + hexG + hexB;
    return hexColor.toUpperCase();
} 

function drawGameBottomLine() {
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.moveTo(0,530);
    canvasContext.lineTo(450,530);
    canvasContext.stroke();
}

function getRandomNum(x,y) {
     radX = Math.random()*theCanvas.width;
     radY = Math.random()*theCanvas.height;
}

function buildCircle() {
    for(var i=0; i<numCircle; i++) {
      do { 
        isDrawable = false;
        radX = Math.random()*theCanvas.width;
        radY = Math.random()*theCanvas.height;
        radR = Math.random()*10+3;
            if ((radX>5 && radX<435) && (radY>0 && radY<520)) {
              circleArray.x[i] = radX;
              circleArray.y[i] = radY;
              circleArray.r[i] = radR;            
                isDrawable = true;
                //canvasContext.fillStyle='#123321;'//getRandomColor();
                //drawCircle(radX,radY,radR,canvasContext);
            }   
        } 
        while (isDrawable == false);
    }
}

function drawCircle(a) {
    for(var i=0; i<numCircle; i++) {
        canvasContext.fillStyle='#123321;'
        drawCircle(circleArray.x[i],circleArray.y[i],circleArray.r[i],canvasContext);
    }
}

drawGameBottomLine();
buildCircle();
drawCircles();
```

[image]

All of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <script>
        var context;
        var rightKey = false;
        var leftKey = false;
        var upKey = false;
        var downKey = false;
        var block_x;
        var block_y;
        var block_h = 10;
        var block_w = 10;

        function init() {
          //canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
          context = $('#myCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
          WIDTH = $('#myCanvas').width();
          HEIGHT = $('#myCanvas').height();
          block_x = WIDTH / 2 - 15;
          block_y = HEIGHT /2 - 15;
          setInterval('draw()', 25);
        }
        function clearCanvas() {
          //context.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        }

        function rect(x,y,w,h) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.rect(x,y,w,h);
          context.endPath();
        }

        function draw() {
          clearCanvas();

          if (rightKey) 
            block_x += 5;
          else if (leftKey) 
            block_x -= 5;

          if (upKey) 
            block_y -= 5;
          else if (downKey) 
            block_y += 5;

          if (block_x <= 0) 
            block_x = 0;

          if ((block_x + block_w) >= WIDTH) 
            block_x = WIDTH - block_w;

          if (block_y <= 0) 
            block_y = 0;

          if ((block_y + block_h) >= HEIGHT) 
            block_y = HEIGHT - block_h;

          context.fillRect(block_x,block_y,block_w,block_h);
        }

        function onKeyDown(evt) {
          if (evt.keyCode == 39) rightKey = true;
          else if (evt.keyCode == 37) leftKey = true;
          if (evt.keyCode == 38) upKey = true;
          else if (evt.keyCode == 40) downKey = true;
        }

        function onKeyUp(evt) {
          if (evt.keyCode == 39) rightKey = false;
          else if (evt.keyCode == 37) leftKey = false;
          if (evt.keyCode == 38) upKey = false;
          else if (evt.keyCode == 40) downKey = false;
        }

        $(document).keydown(onKeyDown);
        $(document).keyup(onKeyUp);
  </script>
  </head>

<body onload="init();">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="450" height="610" style="border:3px solid #c3c3c3;">
It appears that your browser does not support HTML5 and the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var theCanvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvasContext=theCanvas.getContext("2d");
var radX;
var radY;
var radR;
var context;
var numCircle = 50;
var circleArray = new Circles(50);

function Circles(x,y,r) {
    var cX = x;
    var cY = y;
    var cR = r;
}

function clearCanvas() {
  //context.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}

function drawCircle(x,y,r,context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
}

function getRandomColor() {
    // creating a random number between 0 and 255 -- this will set the color of the random sized circle
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);

    // going from decimal to hex -- converts the int value to a hex for the color
    var hexR = r.toString(16);
    var hexG = g.toString(16);
    var hexB = b.toString(16);

    // making sure single character values are prepended with a "0"
    if (hexR.length == 1) hexR = "0" + hexR;
    if (hexG.length == 1) hexG = "0" + hexG;
    if (hexB.length == 1) hexB = "0" + hexB;

    // creating the hex value by concatenatening the string values
    var hexColor = "#" + hexR + hexG + hexB;
    return hexColor.toUpperCase();
} 

function drawGameBottomLine() {
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.moveTo(0,530);
    canvasContext.lineTo(450,530);
    canvasContext.stroke();
}

function getRandomNum(x,y) {
     radX = Math.random()*theCanvas.width;
     radY = Math.random()*theCanvas.height;
}

function buildCircle() {
    for(var i=0; i<numCircle; i++) {
      do { 
        isDrawable = false;
        radX = Math.random()*theCanvas.width;
        radY = Math.random()*theCanvas.height;
        radR = Math.random()*10+3;
            if ((radX>5 && radX<435) && (radY>0 && radY<520)) {
              circleArray.x[i] = radX;
              circleArray.y[i] = radY;
              circleArray.r[i] = radR;            
                isDrawable = true;
                //canvasContext.fillStyle='#123321;'//getRandomColor();
                //drawCircle(radX,radY,radR,canvasContext);
            }   
        } 
        while (isDrawable == false);
    }
}

function drawCircle(a) {
    for(var i=0; i<numCircle; i++) {
        canvasContext.fillStyle='#123321;'
        drawCircle(circleArray.x[i],circleArray.y[i],circleArray.r[i],canvasContext);
    }
}

drawGameBottomLine();
buildCircle();
drawCircles();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you ask a smaller version of the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

It's really pretty simple. You just create an array with something like:

```
var anArray = [];
```

and then add objects to it:

```
anArray.push(object)
```

You might change your definition of a Circle to a simple factory function. Something like this would make everything pretty easy:

```
function Circle(x, y, r){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
}
// create an array
var anArray = [];

// make a circle instance
var aCircle = new Circle(100, 100, 20)
// you can now access the circle properties like this
aCircle.x

//add it to the array
anArray.push(aCircle)

//now this works too (the x coordinate of the first circle in the array):
anArray[0].x
```

I've added a fiddle with a working example pared down to the essentials: http://jsfiddle.net/markm/jxeh0kks/

You have a few errors in your code. The big one is that to access the objects in the array you need to specify the index of the array first.

```
//Don't do this:
circleArray.x[i] = radX;
// Do this:
circleArray[i].x = radX;
```

Comment: Can you show a working copy of this? I could not get this to work yet.

Comment: Added a fiddle with an example above.

Comment: Thank you. When I get home tonight I will give it a try.

Comment: how difficult do you think that it would be to set the array of circle locations and then make them fall from the top of the screen to their respective locations?

Comment: Not sure, I've never tried any animation with the canvas. I've seen topics about canvas animations here, so there's probably some good info floating around.